# how start a program in pacticular directory in c++

Tags: c++, command-line, cmd

I have written a c++ program (`program2.exe`) that I run in `C:\`. I want it to run `program1.exe` that is in `C:\Program Files`.
I do it using

```
system("start C:\Program Files\program1.exe");
```

The program starts successfully but it is executed in `C:\` (where `program2.exe` is), not where `program1.exe` is!

How can fix this problem?

Comment: Change the directory in the program where you call `system`? Call a `.bat` script which changes the directory before executing the program? [Create the process to run the program directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of using `system`, and set the directory for that process?

Comment: the idea is not to use .bat script

Comment: Then why did you tag the question "batch-file"?

Comment: system(""); is kinda batchfile programing

Comment: `system("cd dir");` has the problem that each call creates a new process, and then changes the dir for *that* process only.

Comment: Reading the usage information by entering `Start /?` at the Command prompt, should show you a `/D` option!

Comment: I don't know what the shell command separator is on `Windows` but something like `system("cd my_dir; start C:\Program Files\program1.exe");` might work?

Comment: Note that one backslash '\' is an escape sequence start character.  You'll need 2.  For example, `"C:\\Program Files"`.  Also, you'll need to enclose the directory in double quotes because there is a space: `system("\"C:\\Program Files\\program1.exe");`

Comment: Use `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested example based on my comment, *(using `Start`'s `/D` option)*:

```
system("start \"\" /D \"C:\\Program Files\" program1.exe");
```

For safety, *helps with executable names including spaces etc.*, doublequote the executable name too.

e.g.:

```
system("start \"\" /D \"C:\\Program Files\" \"program 1.exe\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `\` is escaped in C++ literals and that path containign spaces mus be quoted.

Your command should be

```
system("start \"C:\\Program Files\\program1.exe\"");
```

Note how every `\` is doubled and how `"` (in the form of `\"` are added around the path, since it contains a space character.

In the form you wrote it, it will be seen as

"start C:Program Filesprogram1.exe"

with a complete different meaning respect to what you expected.

Comment: `Start` will in this case see `"C:\Program Files\program1.exe"` as a title, in order to remedy that, it is necessary, to introduce a title, _(my answer does that by using an empty title`""`)_. Please also note that the OP isn't 100% clear but appears to want to run the executable with it's holding location as the working directory, your answer doesn't cater for that scenario at all, _(my answer and my comment does so by using `Start`'s `/D` option)_. You'll also note that my answer, _provided more than twenty minutes before yours_, also correctly escapes the doublequotes and backslashes.